# Python regex, searching for prefixes inside a target string

Tags: python, regex, case-insensitive, prefix

I need to find a **list of prefixes** of words inside a **target string** (I would like to have the list of matching indexes in the target string handled as an array).

- I think using **regex** should be the cleanest way.
- Given that I am looking for the pattern "foo", I would like to retrieve in the target string words like "foo", "Foo", "fooing", "Fooing"
- Given that I am looking for the pattern "foo bar", I would like to retrieve in the target string patterns like "foo bar", "Foo bar", "foo Bar", "foo baring" (they are still all handled as prefixes, am I right?)

At the moment, after running it in different scenarios, my Python code still does not work.

- I am assuming I have to use **^** to match the **beginning of a word** in a target string (i.e. a prefix).
- I am assuming I have to use something like **^[fF]** to be **case insensitive with the first letter of my prefix**.
- I am assuming I should use something like **".*"** to let the regexp behave like a **prefix**.
- I am assuming I should use the **\prefix1|prefix2|prefix3** to put in **logic OR many different prefixes** in the pattern to search.

The following source code does not work because I am wrongly setting the `txt_pattern`.

```
import re

#              '            '           '            '                     '             '           '
txt_str = "edb foooooo jkds Fooooooo kj fooing jdcnj Fooing ujndn ggng sxk foo baring sh foo Bar djw Foo";
txt_pattern = ''#???

out_obj = re.match(txt_pattern,txt_str)
if out_obj:
   print "match!"
else:
   print "No match!"
```

1. What am I missing?
2. How should I set the `txt_pattern`?
3. Can you please suggest me a good **tutorial** with **minimum working examples**? At the moment the standard tutorials from the first page of a Google search are very long and detailed, and not so simple to understand.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to match each word from the string separately? Seems like you should `split` the string and then iteratively try to match each word.

Comment: If you are searching for "foo bar" should it match "fooing bar"?

Comment: I think your text_pattern is an empty string (if I'm reading it right) - could that be why you're not matching anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regex is the wrong approach. First parse your string into a list of strings with one word per item. Then use a list comprehension with a filter. The `split` method on strings is a good way to get the list of words, then you can simply do `[item for item in wordlist if item.startswith("foo")]`

People spend ages hacking up inefficient code using convoluted regexes when all they need is a few string methods like `split`, `partition`, `startswith` and some pythonic list comprehensions or generators.

Regexes have their uses but simple string parsing is not one of them.

Answer (score 3):

> I am assuming I have to use ^ to match the beginning of a word in a target string (i.e. a prefix).

No, the `^` is an anchor that only matches the start of the string. You can use `\b` instead, meaning a word boundary (but remember to escape the backslash inside a string literal, or use a raw string literal).

You will also have to use `re.search` instead of `re.match` because the latter only checks the start of the string, whereas the former searches for matches anywhere in the string.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> s = 'Foooooo jkds Fooooooo kj fooing jdcnj Fooing ujndn ggng sxk foo baring sh foo Bar djw Foo'
>>> regex = '((?i)(foo)(\w+)?)'
>>> compiled = re.compile(regex)
>>> re.findall(compiled, s)
[('Foooooo', 'Foo', 'oooo'), ('Fooooooo', 'Foo', 'ooooo'), ('fooing', 'foo', 'ing'), ('Fooing', 'Foo', 'ing'), ('foo', 'foo', ''), ('foo', 'foo', ''), ('Foo', 'Foo', '')]
```

`(?i)`  -> case insensitive
`(foo)` -> group1 matches foo
`(\w+)` -> group2 matches every other word character

```
>>> print [i[0] for i in re.findall(compiled, s)]
['Foooooo', 'Fooooooo', 'fooing', 'Fooing', 'foo', 'foo', 'Foo']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this tool to test some stuff: http://www.pythonregex.com/

Use this reference: docs.python.org/howto/regex.html

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this for your regex:

```
\b(?:([Ff]oo [Bb]ar)|([Ff]oo))\w*
```

Inside of the non-capturing group you should separate each prefix with a `|`, I also placed each prefix inside of its own capturing group so you can tell which prefix a given string matched, for example:

```
for match in re.finditer(r'\b(?:([Ff]oo [Bb]ar)|([Ff]oo))\w*', txt_str):
    n = 1
    while not match.group(n):
        n += 1
    print "Prefix %d matched '%s'" % (n, match.group(0))
```

Output:

```
Prefix 2 matched 'foooooo'
Prefix 2 matched 'Fooooooo'
Prefix 2 matched 'fooing'
Prefix 2 matched 'Fooing'
Prefix 1 matched 'foo baring'
Prefix 1 matched 'foo Bar'
Prefix 2 matched 'Foo'
```

Make sure you put longer prefixes first, if you were to put the `foo` prefix before the `foo bar` prefix, you would only match `'foo'` in `'foo bar'`.